# How to validate TextBox and label values

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

Need to validate label values(get from database) and TextBox values(user enters). If Textbox field value is greater than label value means, have to show error or warning message.

[image]

Comment: What type of values are allowed to be entered..? what do you bean when you say the value is greater than the label value..? what value is in the label.. can you provide code to support what it is you are doing or trying to do...? if you are doing validation on Integer values then just do the Convert.ToInt32(string value) > what ever value you are wanting validate against.. I have never seen anyone use Validation Controls on things like `ASPNET:Label` by the way

Comment: if i entered 6 in textbox field means . have to show error message. its interger.

Comment: this is something so simple `sound` you could even make a property that holds the integer value of the TextBox.Text.. there are so many options you could use `Linq`, `Convert.ToInt32() Method` Etc... you could use `Valadation Controls` which is what I would do as my first choice

Comment: you question title is misleading why ajax? are you using ajax in a sense of asp .net ajax? or you simply trying to validate a user input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple Javascript validator that does what your looking for.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

> [image: output]

#### Script:

```js
document.getElementById( 'numbers' ).addEventListener( 'keyup', function ( event ) {
    if( event.srcElement.className == 'validate' ) {
        var value = event.srcElement.value,
            validationValue = event.srcElement.nextSibling.textContent;
        if( isNaN( value ) ) {
            event.srcElement.nextSibling.className = 'error-nan';
        } else if( parseInt( value ) > parseInt( validationValue ) ) {
            event.srcElement.nextSibling.className = 'error-too-large';
        } else {
            event.srcElement.nextSibling.className = '';
        };
    };
} );
```

#### HTML:

```html
<form id="numbers">
    <input class="validate" /><label>15</label><br />
    <input class="validate" /><label>7</label><br />
</form>
```

#### CSS:

```css
.error-too-large::after {
    color: red;
    content: 'value too large';
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.error-nan::after {
    color: red;
    content: 'value not a number';
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ASP.NET Validation Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). They use client and server validation.